# How to avoid box frame being vanished when combining a graph and Plot3D?

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphs-and-networks, graphics3d, plot-themes

I've combined a graph and a Plot3D as below:-

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[13]; pts = RandomReal[1, {10, 3}]];
graph = NearestNeighborGraph[pts, 2];
image = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Moon"}];
plotBottom = Plot3D[0, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}}, PlotStyle -> Texture[image], BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
Show[graph, plotBottom]
```

[image]
[image]

As you can see, when I added the graph into the Plot3D, the box frames and the ticks vanished. How can I avoid them to vanish?

Many thanks!

Comment: Graphics options are inherited from the first item in `Show`. Either reverse the two items, or add back the box as `Boxed -> True` in `Show`.

Comment: Many thanks. Tried both approaches and they really help.